# Laravel Tailwind Purge PostProcessor - Include classes in PHP file

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, post-processing, css-purge

I am using a form builder package which keeps the classes in the PHP files (see below one example).

However purge is removing these css classes thus they are not applying.

Trying to work if you can can regex a php file as the data is all as follows

Arrays like below..

```
'label_class' => 'ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900 capitalize',
'field_class' => 'h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded'
```

My (current, not working) config.

```
mode: "jit",
purge: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
    "./app/Forms/Auth/LoginForm.php",
],
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Well, you can purge php files aswell, probably path to the file is not correct. Need more details because your current description doesn't tell much. Where are located those arrays with classes?

Comment: @AdrianKokot it turns out this was actually working as intended, the class just wasn't "different" enough for me to notice + some caching on the stylesheet didn't help matters.